# Automation studio to select certain DE's

Tags: journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have my target data extension for my journey, however,the data extension which will inject data into it will change every day. For example, my DE name will be **123456_EM_1** on the Monday,  on the Tuesday is will be **123456_EM_2**, this will continue to 123456_EM_365

How can automation studio select the new DE which has an increment of 1 each day?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Automation Studio there's a starting source (green circle) called "File Drop." You can select it to pull a file that contains certain characters. You will need to have an "Enhanced FTP" set up though.

[image]

Comment: We have enhanced FTP setup, I want to use file name pattern, is it safe to use the import folder for this?